# Where to put widget init/deinit code in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets

I'm building a widget that listens for UDP packets on the network and then updates the child widgets accordingly.

I'm not sure where to put the init code for the socket. It works when I put the call in the build() function but I don't think this is correct as build would be called multiple times.

I have tried creating an initState method but it never gets called.

Any pointers?

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void connectAndListen() {
    int port = 3001;

    // listen forever
    RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, port).then((socket) {
      socket.listen((RawSocketEvent event) {
        if (event == RawSocketEvent.read) {
          Datagram? dg = socket.receive();
          if (dg == null) return;
          final recvd = String.fromCharCodes(dg.data);

          /// send ack to anyone who sends ping
          if (recvd == "ping") socket.send(Utf8Codec().encode("ping ack"), dg.address, port);
          print("$recvd from ${dg.address.address}:${dg.port}");
        }
      });
    });
    print("udp listening on $port");
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    connectAndListen();
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Level Details'),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [


        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Show what you tried when using `initState` and the rest of your class declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of what's going on in your code. But if it's working inside `build` (which can definitely get called multiple times), you can use it in initState also but inside a microtask queue.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  
  // Call your method from microtask queue. This will only get called once. 
  Future.microtask(() {
    connectAndListen();
  });

  // Or better:
  Future.microtask(connectAndListen);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works well. Do you know if the microtask gets killed when the widget closes, for example when a user press 'back' and the widget gets popped?

Comment: @P_J Pressing the back button is also an event which will be added after your microtask has completed. So, you need not worry about it getting killed.